# How to empty a List<T>?

Tags: c#

I have a list:

```
List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
```

I added 10 int values in it:

```
for{i=1;i<10;i++}
    MyList.Add(1);
```

Can I make it empty in one shot, rather than using

- 10 times iteration of `Remove` function
- `RemoveAll` method with a `Predicate<(Of <(T>)>)` generic delegate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`MyList.Clear();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx)